# SQL Group by using two different dates from two tables

Tags: sql, group-by, count, subquery

I have two tables I'm dealing with.

```
select daydate 
from Temp_Dates

results:

**daydate**
2019-01-01 
2019-01-02 
2019-01-03 
2019-01-04 
2019-01-05 
2019-01-06 
2019-01-07 
2019-01-08 
2019-01-09 
2019-01-10 



select Coverage_Effective_Date, Coverage_Expiration_Date, Certificate_Number 
from Elig_dates

results:

*Coverage_Effective_Date     Coverage_Expiration_Date    Certificate_Number*        
2018-12-31                    2019-01-31                   1LEL17-115487         
2019-01-01                    2019-01-31                   1LEL17-115488        
2019-01-01                    2019-01-31                   1LEL17-115494             
2019-01-02                    2019-01-31                   1LEL17-115497         
2019-01-03                    2019-01-31                   1LEL17-115500         
2019-01-05                    2019-01-31                   18LEL18-121770       
2019-01-05                    2019-01-31                   18LELL18-109689       
2019-01-09                    2019-01-31                   ATR16-160410          
2019-01-10                    2019-01-31                   ATR16-160410          
2019-01-10                    2019-01-31                   18LCL18-117965
```

I want to see a count of **Certificate_Number** every time **DayDate** is between **Coverage_Effective_Date** & **Coverage_Expiration_Date** Grouping by **DayDate**

So far here is my code,

```
select DayDate, count(E.certificate_number) as Total
from  Elig_dates E

where dayDate in 
    ( 
select DayDate
from Temp_dates 
where DayDate between E.Coverage_Effective_Date and E.Coverage_Expiration_Date
    ) 

group by  DayDate
```

What i'm looking for is this,

```
**daydate**    **Total**
2019-01-01        3
2019-01-02        4
2019-01-03        5
2019-01-04        5
2019-01-05        7
2019-01-06        7 
2019-01-07        7
2019-01-08        7
2019-01-09        8
2019-01-10        10
```

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables on your condition, then group by daydate and aggregate:

```
select t.daydate, count(*) Total
from Temp_Dates t left join Elig_dates e
on t.daydate between Coverage_Effective_Date and Coverage_Expiration_Date
group by t.daydate
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1fdf6a49e851c94c27e1435fb2983659).
Results:

```
> daydate                 | Total
> :---------------------- | ----:
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |     3
> 2019-01-02 00:00:00.000 |     4
> 2019-01-03 00:00:00.000 |     5
> 2019-01-04 00:00:00.000 |     5
> 2019-01-05 00:00:00.000 |     7
> 2019-01-06 00:00:00.000 |     7
> 2019-01-07 00:00:00.000 |     7
> 2019-01-08 00:00:00.000 |     7
> 2019-01-09 00:00:00.000 |     8
> 2019-01-10 00:00:00.000 |    10
```